# Many-to-Many Tables SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to do a many to many tables between a table MEAL and a table RESTAURANT. First I created the two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE RESTAURANT (
ID_Restaurant VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
ID_Hotel VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
Number_of_Tables INT(3) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (ID_Restaurant),
FOREIGN KEY (ID_Hotel) REFERENCES HOTEL (ID_Hotel));

CREATE TABLE MEAL(
ID_Meal VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
Preparation_Time VARCHAR(20), 
Cooking_Time VARCHAR(20),
PRIMARY KEY (ID_Meal));
```

Then I created the 'joint' tables:

```
CREATE TABLE MEAL_SERVED(
ID_Meal VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
ID_Restaurant VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
Price INT(5) NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (ID_Meal, ID_Restaurant, Price),
FOREIGN KEY(ID_Meal) REFERENCES MEAL(ID_Meal),
FOREIGN KEY(ID_Restaurant) REFERENCES RESTAURANT (ID_Restaurant));
```

I entered some data in the first two tables:

```
INSERT INTO RESTAURANT(ID_Restaurant, ID_Hotel, Name, Number_of_Tables)
VALUES ('REST1', 'H1', 'Benares Indisk Restaurant', 26);
('REST2', 'H2', 'La Gaichel', 35),
('REST3', 'H3', 'Tapas Restaurant', 17),
('REST4', 'H4', 'Faubourg 101', 19),
('REST5', 'H5', 'Pizzeria Roma', 38);

INSERT INTO MEAL(ID_Meal, Name, Preparation_Time, Cooking_Time)
VALUES ('MEAL1', 'Croque-Monsieur', '5 min', '4 min'),
('MEAL2', 'Salad', '6 min', NULL),
('MEAL3', 'Hot Dog', '3 min', '2min'),
('MEAL4', 'Panini', '6 min', '5 min'),
('MEAL5', 'Coca-Cola', NULL, NULL);
```

Until, now there is no problem, but when I tried to enter data in the third tables with:

```
INSERT INTO MEAL_SERVED(ID_Meal, ID_Restaurant, Price)
VALUES ('MEAL1', 'REST1', 50),
('MEAL4', 'REST1', 50),
('MEAL5', 'REST1', 35),
('MEAL1', 'REST2', 3.5),
('MEAL2', 'REST2', 3.5),
('MEAL4', 'REST2', 5);
```

for instance, then I have an error message:

```
FOREIGN KEY constraint failed: INSERT INTO MEAL_SERVED(ID_Meal, ID_Restaurant, Price)
```

I don't understand why I have this message and how to correct it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Run the inserts one by one. See which one fails. Run a select for both tables with the exact key values and see if they are there.

Comment: Varchar id´s... What's wrong with integer?

Comment: They all fail when I try one by one.

Comment: Did the other `INSERT` statements definitely run? Have you checked the tables?

Comment: no idea here, but you are trying to enter non-integer prices like 3.5 into an integer field. Now, I 'm not a MySQL expert, but I wouldn't have thought that was allowed.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error you are receiving. After removing the fk to the hotel table and fixing a typo in your 1st insert query, everything works as expected, see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/91af7/1

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. You gave part of one but you did not run the code you gave. Also next time google your error message without your specific names & read many hits before you ask.

Answer (score 1):

As Shadow said in the comment section.

First, fix your typo in one of your SQL statements:

```
INSERT INTO RESTAURANT(ID_Restaurant, ID_Hotel, Name, Number_of_Tables)
VALUES ('REST1', 'H1', 'Benares Indisk Restaurant', 26);
('REST2', 'H2', 'La Gaichel', 35),
('REST3', 'H3', 'Tapas Restaurant', 17),
('REST4', 'H4', 'Faubourg 101', 19),
('REST5', 'H5', 'Pizzeria Roma', 38);
```

should be:

```
INSERT INTO RESTAURANT(ID_Restaurant, ID_Hotel, Name, Number_of_Tables)
VALUES ('REST1', 'H1', 'Benares Indisk Restaurant', 26),
('REST2', 'H2', 'La Gaichel', 35),
('REST3', 'H3', 'Tapas Restaurant', 17),
('REST4', 'H4', 'Faubourg 101', 19),
('REST5', 'H5', 'Pizzeria Roma', 38);
```

Second:
Do yourself a favor and use integers for primary keys and with the auto_increment option, you can just ignore the id.

```
CREATE TABLE RESTAURANT (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`hotel` INT NOT NULL, 
`name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
`numberOfTables` INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
FOREIGN KEY (hotel) REFERENCES HOTEL (`id`));

CREATE TABLE MEAL(
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
`preparationTime` VARCHAR(20), 
`cookingTime` VARCHAR(20),
PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

CREATE TABLE MEAL_SERVED(
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`meal` INT NOT NULL,
`restaurant` INT NOT NULL,
Price FLOAT NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
FOREIGN KEY(meal) REFERENCES MEAL(`id`),
FOREIGN KEY(restaurant) REFERENCES RESTAURANT (`id`));
```

Data:

```
INSERT INTO RESTAURANT(`hotel`, `name`, `numberOfTables`)
VALUES ('1', 'Benares Indisk Restaurant', 26),
(2, 'La Gaichel', 35),
(3, 'Tapas Restaurant', 17),
(4, 'Faubourg 101', 19),
(5, 'Pizzeria Roma', 38);

INSERT INTO MEAL(`name`, `preparationTime`, `cookingTime`)
VALUES ('Croque-Monsieur', '5 min', '4 min'),
('Salad', '6 min', NULL),
('Hot Dog', '3 min', '2min'),
('Panini', '6 min', '5 min'),
('Coca-Cola', NULL, NULL);

INSERT INTO MEAL_SERVED(`meal`, `restaurant`, `price`)
VALUES (1, 1, 50),
(4, 1, 50),
(5, 1, 35),
(1, 2, 3.5),
(2, 2, 3.5),
(4, 2, 5);
```

Third:
INT(3) has no effects. The space for the INT will be allocated anyway.
You can use TINYINT or SMALLINT instad, maybe. Look here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html

Fourth:
Use camel-case or snake-case but not both please ;-)